# Effect selecting each element of a list, one after the other

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm currently working on a small website with a few pages. A vertical menu is required on the home page. That's the easy part.

I managed to apply the hover effect I need on the vertical menu. It looks like this: https://jsfiddle.net/Kelowna/nfa2h65r/

Markup:

```
    <ul class="list-wave">
        <li class="wave-item"><a class="#" href="#">link1</a></li>
        <li class="wave-item"><a class="#" href="#">link2</a></li>
        <li class="wave-item"><a class="#" href="#">link3</a></li>
        <li class="wave-item"><a class="#" href="#">link4</a></li>
        <li class="wave-item"><a class="#" href="#">link5</a></li>
        <li class="wave-item"><a class="#" href="#">link6</a></li>
      </ul>
```

Script running the effect:

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
$('.list-wave').find('li > a').each(function(){
    $(this).hover( function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({'opacity': '1'}, 300)
        $(this).parents('.wave-item').prevAll().eq(1).children().stop().animate({'opacity': '0.4'}, 300)
        $(this).parents('.wave-item').nextAll().eq(1).children().stop().animate({'opacity': '0.4'}, 300)
        $(this).parents('.wave-item').prev().children().stop().animate({'opacity': '0.6'}, 300)
        $(this).parents('.wave-item').next().children().stop().animate({'opacity': '0.6'}, 300)

}, function() {
     $(this).stop().animate({'opacity': '0.3'}, 300)
     $(this).parents('.wave-item').prevAll().eq(1).children().stop().animate({'opacity': '0.3'}, 300)
     $(this).parents('.wave-item').nextAll().eq(1).children().stop().animate({'opacity': '0.3'}, 300)
     $(this).parents('.wave-item').prev().children().stop().animate({'opacity': '0.3'}, 300)
     $(this).parents('.wave-item').next().children().stop().animate({'opacity': '0.3'}, 300)
})
})
```

});

What I need now is to have that exact same effect, but automatically running in a loop and stop if I hover the menu. Due to my rookie skills with JQuery, I'm having a hard time achieving this. (I tried and managed to apply a class but targeting and applying the effect to multiple elements in an elegant way has given me a hard time).

If someone could give me a hint on how to achieve this one that would be a huge help!

Comment: Do you want effect hover for all elements at once in loop automatically?

Comment: Or make the effect like you were hovering each element from the top?

Comment: not clear what you are asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the time to keep trying to figure out how to achieve it, but here you have some hints:

[setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) execute a function every n millisecs.

[mousenter](https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) / [mouseleave](https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) execute a function when the mouse enters/leaves a selector.

```
<ul class="list-wave">
    <li class="wave-item"><a class="asdf" href="#">link1</a></li>
</ul>
```

don't use '#' to name a class.

https://jsfiddle.net/nfa2h65r/3/ this kinda works

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly what I needed!

the # on class name was a mistake I didn't notice when I edited my fiddle, my bad!

PS: sorry for the other people if I was not clear enough, appriciate that you took time to read my post anyway!